# How to use jQuery Mask Plugin to create a customized time mask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I have a time field where the users can insert the overtime of an employee. In this field they can insert any amount of hour, but the minutes must be between 00 and 59. How could I use the jQuery Mask to make this kind of mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the `translation` option can be used to apply some customized rules on the mask. So, I used a regular expression that allow only numbers between 0 and 5 on the tens of minutes.

```
var time_options = {
    translation: {
        'M': {pattern: /[0-5]/}, 
    }
};
$('.time').mask('00:M0', time_options);
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Comment: @user2132073 "the minutes must be between 00 and 59" I understand this only works in 00 to 50 range.

Comment: @Daniel No. The "0" means that any number between 0 and 9 is allowed.